# Casting choice for The Flash in the Justice League movie?

Tags: casting, dc-extended-universe, the-flash

Why didn't DC Comics choose the TV **"The Flash"** actor **Grant Gustin** for the role of **The Flash** in the **Justice Leagues** movies?

Comment: They specificity want to keep the happy go lucky Grant Flash universe separate from the grim dark movie universe.

Comment: @cde Because the grim dark DC movie universe is *doing so well*, after all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Zack Snyder's own words:

> “I just don’t think it was a good fit,” Snyder told the New York Daily
>   News. “I’m very strict with this universe and I just don’t see a
>   version where…that (tone is) not our world.”
>
> “Even if Grant Gustin is my favorite guy in the world and he’s very
>   good, we made a commitment to the multi-verse (idea), so it’s just not
>   a thing that’s possible,” Snyder said. - [thewrap.com](http://www.thewrap.com/grant-gustin-batman-v-superman-justice-league-the-flash-zack-snyder/)

One more thing to be noted here is that keeping both Flash same also means they are making [Arrowverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrowverse) canon to [DC Extended Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_Extended_Universe). Arrowverse makes 5 shows per year now ( Arrow, Flash, Legend of Tomorrow, Supergirl and Vixen) and DCEU 2 films per year. Making them canon creates a lot of inter-dependencies.

MCU does keep TV and movie verse same but they don't have any major character crossovers. Their TV haven't crossed over to the movies yet. Flash is a main cast of The Flash show and keeping him in DCEU will necessitate a lot of changes on both sides.

[Bustle.com](http://www.bustle.com/articles/150458-why-isnt-grant-gustin-playing-the-flash-in-the-movie-dc-is-changing-things-up) also provided a good Aargument:

> It might come down to it simply not being feasible for Gustin to star
>   in 24-odd episodes of television and lead a huge solo Flash film at
>   the same time. It would, undoubtedly, be a scheduling nightmare for
>   all involved. But based on Snyder's comments, the truth also seems to
>   be that he simply wasn't the studio's top choice for the role. Snyder
>   clearly wants to create the DC Cinematic Universe from scratch,
>   despite the fact that casting Gustin would have been an easy way to
>   expand the DC Cinematic Universe beyond Man of Steel. And though it
>   seems like Gustin would be an obvious choice for the role, it's
>   important to remember that The Flash had barely premiered when the
>   news of Miller's casting was announced. In other words, The Flash
>   simply wasn't the hit it is now.